# Show decimal point number in PHP

Tags: php, database, numbers, format, decimal

I hold decimals in a database using DECIMAL(10,5)

I would like to format these numbers according to a few rules:

- A zero decimal should display as 0
- Show a long decimal (no trailing zero's) with all of it's numbers
- When possible, I would like to only show up to 2 decimal places (when there are trailing zeros)

Here are some examples:

- The left side corresponds to how the number is stored in database.
- The right number is how I would like to display the number in my application.

---

```
0.00000 => 0
0.51231 => 0.51231
0.12000 => 0.12
0.40000 => 0.40
0.67800 => 0.678
12.10000 => 12.10
```

Comment: Your wanted output doesn't seem to follow a determinate pattern. Most have no trailing zeros while two have one. Do you really want to display 0.40000 as 0.40 or would you rather 0.4?

Comment: It makes sense to me. Numbers with a fractional portion should display _at least_ two places behind the decimal. If there are more digits, they should be kept. But don't allow any to display with fewer than two.

Comment: Yes, these are prices and a minimum of 2 decimal places are needed when displaying.

Comment: No, per the question. But I'm curious if all whole numbers should have no ".00" or if that just applies to zero.

Comment: When you say 0.00 it means you are confident that the number is 0 to within one one-hundredth (between -0.005 and 0.005).  When you say 0 it shows no specific confidence.  So...what is this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
function format($x){
    if(!(int)substr_replace($x, '', $dpos = strpos($x, '.'), 1))
        return 0;
    else
        return str_pad((rtrim($x, '0')), $dpos + 3, '0'); 
}
```

[***Example***](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UNKc0u)

Comment: It expects a number with at least 2 decimal places in string format.

Comment: @Godwin You must've been looking at a between edit version? I don't get that.

Comment: I think what you were aiming for is something more like: 

    function format($x){
        if((int)$x == $x) {
            return $x;
        } else {
            return str_pad((rtrim($x, '0')), strpos($x, '.') + 3, '0'); 
        }
    }

Comment: @Godwin No I mentioned in the comment that it expects a string IE `format('12.0000');` It outputs `12.00` in that case which I think is what the OP wanted. If he wants 12 though he'll have to change it to be like yours.

Comment: That's fine, but yours outputs "120" with "12.000" as input and "0" when "1.000" is given. Try adding these to your tests.

Comment: Ok, I tested it further and it works fine when you input strings as you did in your test but fails when actual number are given. If @Justin has data in a numerical format he will have to cast it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I would utilize the number_format function in php to actually do the formatting after you determine the amount of decimal places to the number has.

Source:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Example Usage:

```
$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```

Comment: Of course, this rounds longer numbers off at two decimal places, which is not what the asker wants.

Comment: the second parameter of number_format is the number of decimal points you want, so it would work with a little logic

Answer (score 1):

Well here's one way (I haven't tested it yet so there may be minor errors):

```
$pattern = '/([0-9]+)\\.{0,1}([0-9]*?)0*$/';
$subject = 12.10000;
$matches = array();
$result = preg_match ($pattern, $subject, $matches);
$number = $matches[1];
if ($matches[2] != 0) {
    $number .= '.'.$matches[2];
    if ($matches[2] < 10) {
        $number .= '0';
    }
}
echo $number;
```

And here's another way (probably a little faster):

```
$x = 1.000;
$result = (int)$x;

$trimmed = rtrim($x, 0);
if ($trimmed[strlen($trimmed) - 1] != '.') {
    if ($trimmed[strlen($trimmed) - 2] == '.') {
        $result = $trimmed.'0';
    } else {
        $result = $trimmed;
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: Ok, I've tested it now. It works but there may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but theres the NumberFormatter class: http://php.net/manual/class.numberformatter.php as part of the [Internationalization Functions](http://php.net/manual/book.intl.php) for this stuff. Using that is a little more involved i think though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the following quick function I wrote for my own project might help someone looking for this.

```
function number_format_least_dp($number, $decimal_point = '.', $thousand_seperator = ','){
    if (floatval($number) == (int)$number){
        $number = number_format($number, 0, $decimal_point, $thousand_seperator);
    } else {
        $number = rtrim($number, '.0');
        $number = number_format($number, strlen(substr(strrchr($number, '.'), 1)), $decimal_point, $thousand_seperator);
    }
    return $number;
}
```